# How to echo text labels before array values for specific indexes

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, label, echo

I have written the following PHP code, I want to generate a similar table as shown in the screenshot:

The table should also have title like `Job:` and `Email:` before job name and email address. Thanks

```
<?php

$company = array
  (

  array("John Smith","Accountant","johnsmith@example.com", 70),
  array("May Black","Business Analyst","mayblack@example.com", 40),
  array("Tom white","Plummer","tomwhite@example", 30),
  array("Susan Kim","Engineer","susankim@example.com", 80)

  );

  echo "--Customer List-- <br> <br>";

  for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
      for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo $company[$i][$j]."<br>";  

      }
      echo "<br><br>";
  }

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define an array for the titles as well and (conditionally) echo those first (if they are not empty strings). Note that I used a `foreach` loop to not have to investigate how many employees there are in the array. I've still kept the inner loop (`[0-3)`) to not display the sensitive age information (although that could be controlled in a different manner).

```php
<?php
  $company = array(
    array("John Smith", "Accountant", "johnsmith@example.com", 70),
    array("May Black", "Business Analyst", "mayblack@example.com", 40),
    array("Tom white", "Plummer", "tomwhite@example", 30),
    array("Susan Kim", "Engineer", "susankim@example.com", 80)
  );

  $title = array("", "Job", "Email", "Age");

  echo "--Customer List--<br><br>\n";

  foreach($company as $employee) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
      if($title[$j]) echo $title[$j] . ": ";
      echo $employee[$j] . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br>\n";
  }
?>
```

Another option can be handy if you want to control how an employee is displayed from one place: By creating a `class` and a member function to display the (appropriate) information, you need only to change the display function when you want to change how the employee information is displayed everywhere it's called. It also adds other advantages like keeping the code that deals with objects of a certain type close to the code that defines the type.

```
<?php
    class Employee {
        public $Name;
        public $Job;
        protected $Email;
        private $Age;

        public function __construct($n, $j, $e, $a) {
            $this->Name = $n;
            $this->Job = $j;
            $this->Email = $e;
            $this->Age = $a;
        }

        public function display($delim = "<br>") {
            echo $this->Name . $delim;
            echo "Job: " . $this->Job . $delim;
            echo "Email: " . $this->Email . $delim;
            echo $delim . $delim;
            echo "\n";
        }
    }

    $employees = array(
        new Employee("John Smith","Accountant","johnsmith@example.com", 70),
        new Employee("May Black","Business Analyst","mayblack@example.com", 40),
        new Employee("Tom white","Plummer","tomwhite@example", 30),
        new Employee("Susan Kim","Engineer","susankim@example.com", 80)
    );

    echo "--Customer List--<br><br>\n";
    foreach($employees as $employee) {
        $employee->display();
    }
?>
```